# Add and remove async event handlers using reflection in c#

Tags: c#, events, reflection, delegates

I have the following code sample that actually works:

```
namespace DeviceLib
{
    public interface IInstrument
    {
        event Action<InstrumentConnectionStatus> OnConnectionChanged;
        event Action OnRemoteMeasureRequested;
    }

public class InstrumentInstance
{
    public delegate Task EventCompletedHandler(object sender, dynamic eventArgs);
    public event EventCompletedHandler StatusChanged = async delegate { };
    public event EventCompletedHandler RemoteMeasureRequested = async delegate { };
    IInstrument Instrument;

    public InstrumentInstance(string DriverName)
    {
        Instrument = DriverName switch
        {
            Instrument1.DRIVER => new Instrument1Driver(),
            instrument2.DRIVER => new Instrument2Driver(),
            _ => throw new NotSupportedException($"Driver {DriverName} not supported"),
        };
    }

    public async Task<object> OnStatusChanged()
    {
        Instrument.OnConnectionChanged += async (InstrumentConnectionStatus status) =>
        {
            await StatusChanged(nameof(OnStatusChanged), status.ToString());
        };

        return null;
    }

    public async Task<object> OnRemoteMeasureRequested()
    {
        Instrument.OnRemoteMeasureRequested += async () =>
        {
            await RemoteMeasureRequested(nameof(OnRemoteMeasureRequested), null);
        };

        return null;
    }
}
```

}

```
namespace DeviceConsumer 
{
    public class InstrumentService
    {
        static Type Type = typeof(DeviceLib.InstrumentInstance);
        DeviceLib.InstrumentInstance InstrumentInstance;
        static List<MethodInfo> AvailableEventHandlers =  Type.GetMethods().Where(x => x.DeclaringType == Type && !x.IsSpecialName && x.Name.StartsWith("On")).ToList();
        static List<EventInfo> AvailableEvents=Type.GetEvents().ToList();
    

        public InstrumentService()
        {

        }

        public async Task CreateInstrumentInstance(string driverName)
        {
            this.InstrumentInstance = new DeviceLib.InstrumentInstance(driverName);
        
        
            // Invoking the methods that wrap the event handlers with reflection
            foreach (MethodInfo eventHandler in AvailableEventHandlers)
                await (Task<object>)eventHandler.Invoke(InstrumentInstance, new object[] { });


            InstrumentInstance.StatusChanged +=  async(s,e) => await ProcessInstrumentEvent(s,e);
            InstrumentInstance.RemoteMeasureRequested += async (s, e) => await ProcessInstrumentEvent(s, e);
        }

        private async Task ProcessInstrumentEvent(object sender, dynamic eventArgs)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.Write($"Event {sender} Fired!");
            });
        }

}
```

Now I want to substitute the static part that associates the events to the ProcessInstrumentEvent method:

```
InstrumentInstance.StatusChanged +=  async(s,e) => await ProcessInstrumentEvent(s,e);
InstrumentInstance.RemoteMeasureRequested += async (s, e) => await ProcessInstrumentEvent(s, e);
```

With something like:

```
        foreach (EventInfo ev in AvailableEvents)
        {
           // EventHandler handler = async delegate (object s, dynamic e) { await ProcessInstrumentEvent(s, e); };
          
           //  EventHandler handler = new EventHandler(async (s, e) => await ProcessInstrumentEvent(s,e));


             ev.AddEventHandler(InstrumentInstance, handler);

        }
```

None of the 2 approaches to define "handler" worked, where I'm failing here? I think I'm very close, the goal of this implementation is to dynamically add (and later remove) the handlers that target the method "ProcessInstrumentEvent" in class "InstrumentService" so without using += and -= operators, so I thought that I could achieve that using the reflection methods "AddEventHandler" and "RemoveEventHandler"

Comment: as a side note: the `dynamic eventArgs` strikes me as being... unnecessary and confusing

Comment: It worked and I've understood where the error was, thank you so much!   PS "dynamic eventargs" is unnecessary in this sample but I need it in the real implementation because some of these events when fired also carry additional output data that I need to process later in "ProcessInstrumentEvent" method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```cs
var obj = new InstrumentInstance("foo");

EventCompletedHandler handler = async (s, e) => await ProcessInstrumentEvent(s, e);

foreach (var evt in obj.GetType().GetEvents(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
    if (evt.EventHandlerType == typeof(EventCompletedHandler))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Binding '{evt.Name}'");
        evt.AddEventHandler(obj, handler);
    }
}
```

It should also work without the extra indirection:

```cs
EventCompletedHandler handler = ProcessInstrumentEvent;
```